# How check for changes in select menu in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

How do know using openedChange that when you close or open the mat select panel it will show if there is an item on the select box that was check or uncheck.

Right now I can only detect if it is open or close , I wanna to detect that when I close it if there is any activity or select items on the select menu. Thanks.

I want to check if there are any changes.

#html code

```
 <mat-form-field class="job-filter" appearance="fill">
          <mat-select #select [formControl]="marketDropdownMultiCtrl" placeholder="Market" [multiple]="true" #marketDropdownMultiSelect (openedChange)="changeFilterEvent($event,select)">
              <mat-option>
                <ngx-mat-select-search 
                [showToggleAllCheckbox]="true" 
                accesskey="" 
                placeholderLabel="Search Market filter" 
                noEntriesFoundLabel="'No results found'" 
                (toggleAll)="toggleSelectAllMarket($event)" 
                [toogleAllCheckboxTooltipPosition]="'above'"
                [toggleAllCheckboxChecked]="marketDropdownMultiCtrl?.value?.length === marketDropdownSize" 
                [toggleAllCheckboxIndeterminate]="marketDropdownMultiCtrl?.value?.length > 0 && marketDropdownMultiCtrl?.value?.length < marketDropdownSize"
                [toggleAllCheckboxTooltipMessage]="'Select / Deselect all Market filters'" 
                [formControl]="marketDropdownMultiFilterCtrl">
              </ngx-mat-select-search>
              </mat-option>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let market of filteredMarketListMulti | async" [value]="market">
                  {{market.description}}
              </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
```

[image]

#tscode

```
changeFilterEvent(opened:boolean,element:any){ }
```

Comment: on select or check/uncheck you can push the respected item in an array and by checking the array item you can know if there were any changes or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before open make a copy of marketDropdownMultiCtrl.value -

```
this.oldValue=marketDropdownMultiCtrl.value
```

After close compare values

```
if (marketDropdownMultiCtrl.value!=this.oldValues)
        ...do something..
})
```

if you want check any change in the same time you check/uncheck any value you can also subscribe to this.marketDropdownMultiCtrl.valueChanges using pipe pairwise

```
ngOnInit()
{
   this.marketDropdownMultiCtrl=new FormControl(null);
 
   this.marketDropdownMultiCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
      //it's necesary send a first value
      startWith(this.marketDropdownMultiCtrl.value), 
      pairwise())  //the pairwise make the "magic"
       .subscribe(([old,value])=>{
          if (old!=value)
          {
              console.log("I change from "+old+" to "+value)
          }
      })
```

Comment: `o$.pipe(startWith(v))` is deprecated. Use `concat(of(v),o$)` instead.